# How to filter selection document to prevent user from select different document based on field "status"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Before this I ask this question and @Torsten Link suggest that I filter document to prevent user from select different document. Basically I have view, and in this view I have list of document sort by Faulty Status which I set as PFStatus. So I have three status which is **Obsolete**, **Spoilt**, and **Not Found**. So I want to filter so that user choose either these three status only and cannot be mixed up.

So I try to filter using below code but nothing happened.

```
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()
    If (doc.PFStatus(0) = "Obsolete" And doc.PFStatus(0) = "Spoilt" And doc.PFStatus(0) = "Not Found") Then
        Messagebox"Please choose either one Write Off selection!"
        Exit Sub
    Elseif (doc.PFStatus(0) = "Obsolete" And doc.PFStatus(0) = "Spoilt") Then
        Msgbox"Please choose only one Write Off selection!"
        Exit Sub
    Elseif (doc.PFStatus(0) = "Obsolete" And doc.PFStatus(0) = "Not Found") Then
        Msgbox"Please choose only one Write Off selection!"
        Exit Sub
    Elseif (doc.PFStatus(0) = "Spoilt" And doc.PFStatus(0) = "Not Found") Then
        Msgbox"Please choose only one Write Off selection!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Some code...
    End If
```

So how can I filter selection of documents? Did I put the code in wrong way? Any help I really appreciate. Thank you. :)

### Update question

Below are my view name "WriteOff". And I have a button to create new batch. So I want to try prevent user from create a batch with mixed up Faulty Status.

[image: pic]

Comment: Pls explain how, at the same time, doc.PFStatus(0) can have two values, "Obsolete" and "Spoilt" ??

Comment: Hello @D.Bugger, I'm using combobox field for my PFStatus with three values which are obsolete, spoilt, and not found. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: PFStatus is multivalue, but doc.PFStatus(0) is the first value of PFStatus. So PFStatus(0) cannot be "Obsolete" and "Spoiled" at the same time, meaning that neither of your cases will work.
Am I correct that a user can select multiple documents in the "WriteOff" view but all these documents must have the same value in "PFStatus"?
If so, and multiple values are selected, do all values have to match, or is a single match sufficient?

Comment: Hi @TomVanAken, yes. When user select multiple documents, document must have only same value either "Obsolete", "Spoilt", or "Not Found". I only want to check PFStatus value only. Because I want to create a batch and for each batch will be only one status per batch. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample on how to do this

Best is not to put your code in the button, but to create an agent to put your code in. Like this, you don't need to refresh your view while debugging your code.

Set 'Agent list selection' as trigger and Target = None.

[image]

Create a button in the view using the following formula (replace 'batch process' by your agent name):

```
@Command([ToolsRunMacro];"(batch process)")
```

Here's an example of the agent code on how you can check if pfstatus in selected docs is the same.

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
Dim col As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim vwUI As NotesUIView
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim dbcurrent As NotesDatabase
Set dbCurrent = session.currentdatabase

'Use vwui.documents to keep documents selected if the agent runs. 
'Like this, a user can deselect a faulty document.
'Don't forget to deselect all docs at the end of your code  
Set vwui = ws.Currentview
Set col = vwui.Documents

'If a user did not 'select' a document (eg V marker before the docline), but merely positioned on a document,
'you need to create a single doc collection based on the caretnoteid (= id of selected document)
If col.count = 0 And vwui.caretnoteid <> "" Then
    Set doc = dbCurrent.Getdocumentbyid(vwui.caretnoteid)
    Set col = dbCurrent.createdocumentcollection()
    Call col.Adddocument(doc)
End If

'Get status from first document to get status to compare against
Dim statusRef As String
Set doc = col.getfirstdocument
If doc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'avoid error when no doc is selected
statusRef = doc.pfStatus(0)

'loop other selected documents to compare status
Set doc = col.getNextDocument(doc)
While Not doc Is Nothing
    If doc.pfStatus(0) <> statusRef Then
        'A document with another status is selected, so do not continue
        Msgbox"Please choose only one Write Off selection!"
        Exit sub
    End If
    Set doc = col.getNextDocument(doc)
Wend

'If code gets here, you can loop all documents again to do you batch processing
'Reset doc to first doc in selected collection
Set doc = col.getfirstdocument()
While Not doc Is Nothing
'... some code to run on current doc in the loop ...
    Set doc = col.getNextDocument(doc)
Wend


'Deselect documents at the end of your code
Call vwui.Deselectall()
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how to say thank you to you but, Thank you @TomVanAken! I implement your code and make some changes in 'If col.count = 0 And vwui.caretnoteid <> ""' and it worked so perfect. You also gave me an idea to create another Agent. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Is PFStatus a multi-value field? If it isn't, it can never have more than 1 value (unless you set more than one value programmatically). Or is it a checkbox field?

I think it would be the best if you simply disallow the selection of documents from multiple categories in the view. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ONSELECT_EVENT.html

---

IMHO a status field should never be directly input by the user. You should have buttons that guide the user to perform some functions AND change the status in the meantime.

Comment: Hi D.Bugger. The field is multi-value field and I use combobox field. I update in question my "view". So what I'm going to do is, when user select document obsolete and document spoilt in same time, and I click the button in this view, I try to show error message. Also, what you mean by I should have the buttons?

Comment: A combobox has only one value, so what you're testing "cannot happen", there's no need to do those tests. What you can test is whether the field has a (one) value, but that can more easily be done using field validation in the form.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you use buttons that change the status, the user doesn't understand what a status is. For instance, a button "Accept" will check first if the document can be accepted, then maybe set some values etc. and finally set the status to "Accepted".

Comment: Hi @D.Bugger. Because this PFStatus need to manually set by user so I was thinking by doing this way. And I only want to prevent in view when I create "Batch" and it is a button in my view. Any other way other than "Accept"?

Comment: Considering the updated question info, I have to say that the status and buttons suggestion was not helpful, sorry for that. The status here is for the equipment, and it's not a document status. Please ignore my remark. Or shall I remove it from my answer?

Comment: Okay Thank you. But how can I use my field into that onselect? I don't understand how to insert my field into it. Also now I'm using a button, how can I use this onselect?

Comment: Each time a document is selected, the OnSelect is activated, and you get info about the selected document in CaretNoteId, so you can get that document and inspect the value of PFStatus.

Comment: Okay, so I use CaretNoteId to select document. Then I used my code in my question to inspect value of PFStatus right?

Comment: I already tried but it show error on "caretNoteID$ = Source.CaretNoteID" not a member CARETNOTEID.

Comment: Your variable Source is a NotesUIView object? PS See Discord